# Linked Files in wwwroot Are Not Accessible While Running

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm creating an example project for a varying number of generated web files. These web files exist outside the example project. I wish to include these files in the wwwroot/ folder, preferably as a reference rather than a copy. I have successfully added them as a reference in the Solution Explorer, but they're not picked up during runtime.

I added the following to my .csproj file:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\..\bin\**" Link="wwwroot\lib\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

While this adds the files to the Solution Explorer, they're not accessible from the browser while running the program. I suspect this is because there are no physical files in the wwwroot/ folder. I tried to add the files to the output directory with:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\..\bin\**" Link="wwwroot\lib\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This had the expected result of copying the files to the output directory, but they're still inaccessible from the web.

This is my Program.cs:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.Run();
```

Can I make the UseStaticFiles method respect linked files or use the files from the output directory? Is there another better solution?

Comment: By default, the UseStaticFiles middleware serves files from the wwwroot directory in your project.1) In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the wwwroot folder and select "Add" -> "Existing Item".
2)Browse to the location of the external web files and select them.
3)Instead of clicking the "Add" button, click the arrow next to it and select "Add as Link". This will create a reference to the files instead of copying them. or you have to use the custom middleware to service the files

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try below code to serve the static files from the outside of the project root folder without copying:

index.cshtml:

```
<img src="~/StaticFiles/images/MyImage.jpg" class="img" alt="MyImage" />
```

Program.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "C:\\MyStaticFiles")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
});
// Update the default provider.

app.UseStaticFiles();
```

[image]

[image]

Here is the official document if you would like to get more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0